# How to sort by sum of field of a relation on sails.js?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I searched a lot about sorting elements by sum of votes (in another model), like I do in SQL here :

```
SELECT item.* FROM item
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    vote.item,
    SUM(vote.value) AS vote.rating
  FROM vote
  GROUP BY vote.item
) AS res ON item.id = vote.item
ORDER BY res.rating DESC
```

Is there a way to do it via waterline methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do the left join with simple waterline methods, but you can use the [.query](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query-methods.md#query-query-data-callback-) method to execute your raw SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Sails MySQL adapter makes `sum('field')` conflict with `sort('field')`. It will generate SQL query like:

```
SELECT SUM(table.field) AS field FROM table ORDER BY table.field;
```

But I want:

```
SELECT SUM(table.field) AS field FROM table ORDER BY field;
```

It same as:

```
SELECT SUM(table.field) AS f FROM table ORDER BY f;
```

My solution is using `lodash.sortBy()` to process results. https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#sortBy